# In C#; what is the most efficent way to check for changes from a background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I create a thread for each of my network communications and they add to a list responses whenever they hear back from a client.  I'm starting up the task below at execution to see if any communications come in.  It displays the most recent one on screen.

```
Task task = new Task(
(() =>
 {
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (responses.Count > i){
            Debug.WriteLine(responses[i]);
            int index = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.IndexOfKey("responseBox");
            Form.ActiveForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => Form.ActiveForm.Controls[index].Visible = true));
            Form.ActiveForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => Form.ActiveForm.Controls[index].Text = responses[i]));
            i++;
        }
    }
 }));
task.Start();
```

My question is; is there a better way for me to do this?  It seems wrong to me to have the task constantly working for something that doesn't happen very often.

Edit: I'm very new to C#, so if there's something obvious please don't hesitate to point it out.

Update:

As per the nice tutorial from MS that sidewinder linked I added a simple event to the Add function of List.  as So:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class listWithChanges<T> : List<T> 
{
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

    protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, e);
    }

    public new void Add (T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

and added to my output with a delegate

```
responses.Changed += ((o, e) => {
                                int index = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.IndexOfKey("responseBox");
                                Form.ActiveForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => Form.ActiveForm.Controls[index].Visible = true));
                                Form.ActiveForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => Form.ActiveForm.Controls[index].Text = responses[responses.Count - 1]));
                              });
```

Comment: why don't you just raise events?

Comment: because I'm new to c# and have no idea what you mean :)

Comment: Events are the way to go in C# for this kind of action, if you need a tutorial to get started here is the one provided by MS : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: That doesn't look like much of a background worker.  It looks like a job for just a timer on the main thread or an event for whenever `responses` has a new item.

Comment: If using WPF you can use Bindings to get the list displayed but it would be a little more difficult than the events

Comment: What is `responses`? Could you show us how it is defined and how it is used? The solution I think is to replace your `responses` with either an `ObservableCollection` (if you really do need to be storing the incoming things), otherwise you should replace it with an event which is fired by whatever is adding to the collection (with the new item), and a handler (async if long running) that processes it.

Comment: Events are very nice, I'm definitely going to be using them more often.  I added an on change event, like the one in the tutorial Sidewinder linked, to my list and it works perfectly.  There was a slight delay before between receiving a message and displaying it, that delay isn't noticeable anymore.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to look at this.  If you want your monitor-for-responses code completely independent of your communication threads, then Lars had a good suggestion.  Have a timer that wakes up every so often to check on your responses.  If, instead, you want to have Something Happen whenever each of your threads hears from a client, then you want to embed an event call in your communication thread task.  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: I need to display the newest message to my form as soon as it comes in, events seem to do this well.  I was going to use timers, instead of the infinite loop I originally had, but I didn't want any added delay.

Comment: Excuse me guys, how are events going to work when the event is received by a thread which is different from the thread that issued the event?

Comment: @MikeNakis it doesn't seem to care.  I define my list in my main thread and call Add from within one of my network threads and the event is called without issue.

Comment: Okay, well, if this works, good for you.  My impression was that WinForms will throw, crash, or both if invoked from a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Oh, I see now, you do those `Invoke` - `MethodInvoker` stuff to be thread safe.  Still, I would advice to put everything you need to do inside a single invoke() call instead of making two separate `invoke()` calls.  For performance, and also for correctness: threads may pre-empt each other between the separate `invoke()` calls, yielding weird behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events would be a nice solution.

An event is an implementation of the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern, in which the source (the network communications) warn  it's observers(whoever calls the task in your example) that something happened.

It's a lot more efficient since it doesn't waste CPU usage in an infinite loop, the method only executes when a client responds.

C# has a great support for events, consider reading the [MS Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)(originally posted by Sidewinder94).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have to go through great restructuring of your code, you can use a *blocking queue* for your `responses` collection, so that your reading thread blocks while waiting for an item to appear in the queue.

Waiting for something to appear in a blocking queue consumes zero CPU.  (Technically non-zero, but nonetheless unnoticeable.)

A quick search yields this: [MSDN - BlockingCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)